# Tree implementation throwing a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, tree

I have a tree :

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> parent;
    private Map<T, Node<T>> children;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        if (this.children != null) {
            return this.children.size() > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        parent.addChild(this);
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(T data) {
        Node<T> child = new Node<T>(data);
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.put(child.data, child);
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.put(child.data, child);
    }
}
```

Then, I try to populate it like this :

```
Node<String> parentNode = new Node<String>("Parent");
Node<String> childNode = new Node<String>("Child");
childNode.setParent(parentNode);
```

This throws a `StackOverflowError`, because we are stuck in the loop setParent - addChild.

I tried another way :

```
Node<String> parentNode = new Node<String>("Parent");
Node<String> childNode = new Node<String>("Child", parentNode);
```

However, `childNode.parent.children` is null, and I'd like it to have the `childNode` in it.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Where in the `Node(T, Node<T>)` constructor do you think you're adding the new child to the parent's map of children? (In general, it's not clear what you're trying to ask in this question... why the new code doesn't work, or about the stack overflow?)

Comment: @Jon Skeet : edited, is it better ?

Comment: Not really, because it's still not obvious whether you're trying to fix that second constructor, or address the fact that `childNode.setParent(parentNode)` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take recursion out of the picture and handle the consistency of parent-child relationship in the application layer ( i.e. use `childNode.setParent(parentNode);` and `parentNode.addChild(parentNode);` together). You can use the code below, it will handle both ways.

```
public class Node<T> {
private T data;
private Node<T> parent;
private Map<T, Node<T>> children;

public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
    parent.addChild( this);
}

public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public boolean hasChildren() {
    if (this.children != null) {
        return this.children.size() > 0;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void addChild(T data) {
    Node<T> child = new Node<T>(data);
    this.children.put(child.data, child);
}

public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
    this.children.put(child.data, child);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `setParent` and `addChild` are calling each other. To keep both calls to addChild or setParent are valid, an option would be to create a `setParentInternal` private method, called by `addChild` instead of the public `setParent`.

Note that I also refactored the addChild to reduce reduncuncy and initialized the children list.

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> parent;
    private Map<T, Node<T>> children= new HashMap<T, Node<T>>();

    public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        if (this.children != null) {
            return this.children.size() > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setParentInternal(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        parent.addChild(this);
        setParentInternal(parent);
    }

    public void addChild(T data) {
        addChild(new Node<T>(data));
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
        child.setParentInternal(this);
        this.children.put(child.data, child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a stackOverflow exception because your "addChild" method call your "setParent" method and your "setParent" method call "addChild"